# Instantiate an object into a class with namespace

Tags: php, class, namespaces, instance

I don't know how to explain it, but I will do my best. Ok, I have these three files:

- Theme.php

  ```
  path: /shared/models/Theme.php
  class: Theme
  namespace: namespace models;
  ```
- Custom.php

  ```
  path: /themes/default/Custom.php
  class: Custom
  namespace: this class does not use namespace
  ```
- Settings.php

  ```
  path: /controllers/Settings.php
  class: Settings
  namespace: this class does not use namespace
  ```

In my `Settings.php` looks like:

```
<?php
class Settings
{
    public function apply()
    {
        $theme = new \models\Theme();
        $theme->customize(); // in this method the error is triggered
    }
}
```

Now, look `Theme` class below:

```
<?php
namespace models;

class Theme
{
    public function customize()
    {
        $ext = "/themes/default/Custom.php";
        if (file_exists($ext))
        {
            include $ext;
            if (class_exists('Custom'))
            {            
                $custom = new Custom(); 
                //Here, $custom var in null, why???
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the code, I get the following error:

```
Message: require(/shared/models/Custom.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Line Number: 64
```

Why the interpreter is trying to load the `Custom` class from another directory instead of specified with `$ext` var?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When invoking `new Custom()` inside of a class in `\models` namespace you're actually trying to instantiate `\models\Custom`. Since you say your `Custom` class "has no namespace", try `new \Custom()` instead.

The error you get seems to be coming from some class autoloader that tries to require class file for `\models\Custom` and fails.

Comment: Yes, you are totally correct. This is very important to keep in mind: `Since you say your Custom class "has no namespace", try new \Custom() instead.` Thank you so much :)